# osmium export bounds from osm file to geojson

Tags: osmium, pyosmium

I'd like to have a geojson file from an osm map since they are easier to parse.
My problem is that when I export the osm with:

```
osmium export mymap.osm  -o mymap.geojson
```

I don't get the information in the <bounds> tag

```
<bounds minlat="43.3733900" minlon="9.4305600" maxlat="43.3787000" maxlon="9.4363400"/>
```

If I use osmium in python, I can get it through the reader with

```
reader.header().box()
```

But then I have to parse everything else to generate something accessible like a geojson file.
What parameter for osmium would return the bounding box defined in the osm file? If there isn't, how do I implement pyosmium to obtain something similar to the "export" command of osmium?